# Triangle inequality on matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, solution-verification

For $A=(a_{ij})\in\mathcal{M}_{n}$, let $$||A||=\mathop{\max}_{i\in[1,n]}\left\{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|\right\}$$ be the norm of $A$.

Prove $||A+B||\leq||A||+||B||$.

Attempt:

By the triangle inequality, $\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}+b_{ij}|\leq\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|+\sum_{j=1}^{n}|b_{ij}|$ for all $i,j$. If $i'$ is the row such that $||A+B||=\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{i'j}+b_{i'j}|$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{i'j}+b_{i'j}|&\leq\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{i'j}|+\sum_{j=1}^{n}|b_{i'j}|\\
    &\leq||A||+||B||.
\end{align*}

Comment: I think it looks correct. But “for all i,j” should be just “for all i”

Comment: You might as well finish off by taking the $\max$.